# Shortest code for printing line startswith ['a', 'b'] and endswith ['y', 'z'] Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, startswith, ends-with

For an assignment I have to print lines from a text that start with "W" and "Z" and end in "n" and "t" (so W-n, W-t, Z-n, Z-t combo's). I have a code now that works, but it seems a bit long and I was wondering if there is a way to shorten it?

This is the code:

```
import sys

def main():

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith("W") and line.endswith("n"):
                print(line)
        if line.startswith("W") and line.endswith("t"):
                print(line)
        if line.startswith("Z") and line.endswith("n"):
                print(line)
        if line.startswith("Z") and line.endswith("t"):
                print(line)

main()
```

As I said, it works, but it seems a bit elaborate. Any tips on how to shorten?

I tried `line.startswith("Z","W")` and `line.endswith("t","n")` but I get a Type Error (all slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__method).

Comment: Look up regular expression. It will allow you to find patterns like that in a lot less code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

```
line = line.rstrip()
if line and line[0] in "WZ" and line[-1] in "nt":
    print(line)
```

Or use regular expressions:

```
import re 
# ...
if re.match(r'^[WZ].*[nt]$', line):
    print(line)

# ^ beginning of string
# $ end of string
# [WX] matches W or X
# .*  any character 0 or more times
```

See the [docs on Python regex syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: `re.match` captures only if the match starts at the beginning of the string; the `^` can be removed

Comment: I actually agree; I use `search` instead of `match` usually and then it's required.

Answer (score 3):

`startswith` and `endswith` also accept a tuple as argument (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)).
So this will work:

```
line.startswwith(('W', 'Z'))
line.endswith(('t','n'))
```

Your code could shorten to:

```
import sys

def main():

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith(("W", "Z")) and line.endswith(("n", "t")):
                print(line)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `regex`.

```
import re

pattern = '[ZW].*[nt]$'

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    mo = re.match(p, line)
    if mo:
        print(line)
```

Pattern explained:

- `[ZW]` matches one of the two characters; because we use `re.match`, it matches only if the string begins with the pattern. So it has to start with Z or W
- `.*` matches anything; char, int, space, etc. one or more times
- `[nt]$` means match n or t (lower case) and `$` makes it a match only if the **line ends** with these values

Comment: Printing `mo.group()` seems a bit perverse. The requirement was to print the line so just `print(line)` should suffice.

Comment: You're right. I copied the code I tested, and forget to change that :-) thanks

Comment: and the question has the python-3.x tag so print function preferred.

Answer (score 0):

or you could use a regex

```
import re

r = re.compile(r^"[WZ].+[nt]$")

m = r.match('Woot')
m.group()
```

Answer (score 0):

str.startswith allows you to supply a tuple of strings , you have to use a tuple ("Z", "W") not "Z", "W".

```
import sys
def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith(("Z","W")) and line.endswith(("t","n")):
       print(line)
main()
```